# Input field not binding with the state

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to bind the input to the state. When doing so I'm stuck where the input value is being captured in onChange function and updated to the state however the JSON object (`{JSON.stringify(data.MetricsData)}`) that's on the UI doesn't update.

The output result should `JSON.stringify(data.MetricsData)` to be updated with the latest value that's on the input.

The following is the simplified code:

```
let obj = [];

function Metrics() {
  obj["MetricsData"] = MetricsDataObj()
  const [data, setData] = useState(obj);

  function onChange(event){
    let value = event.target.value;
    data.MetricsData[0].year1 = value;
    setData(() => {
      console.log(data)
      return data;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <br/><br/>
      {JSON.stringify(data.MetricsData)}
    </div>
  );
}

function MetricsDataObj(){
  return [
    { id: 1, name: 'Month 1', year1: '' }
  ];
}

export default Metrics;
```

Comment: Try passing value to <input /> to make it controlled, `<input value={data.MetricsData[0]} />` something like so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a copy from the `state` before update its value. In addition the way which you have selected for updating the `state` is not correct. Try this:

```
import { useState } from "react";

let obj = [];
function Metrics() {
  obj["MetricsData"] = MetricsDataObj()
  const [data, setData] = useState(obj);

  function onChange(event){
    let value = event.target.value;
    const copy = {...data};
    copy.MetricsData[0].year1 = value;
    setData(copy);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.00" step="0.01" onChange={(e) => onChange(e)} />
      <br/><br/>
      {JSON.stringify(data.MetricsData)}
    </div>
  );
}

function MetricsDataObj(){
  return [
    { id: 1, name: 'Month 1', year1: '' }
  ];
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Metrics/>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit smoosh-grass-v8qyhb]